# DataBind() in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-entities

I am fairly new to Entity framework as well as LINQ. I have used DataGridView before and to set the datasource to it

```
DataGridView1.datasource=dt; // dt=datatable
```

was enough. But while reading ASP.Net book they have given the code using Entity Framework as

```
using (PlanetWroxEntities myEntities = new PlanetWroxEntities())
{
    var allGenres = from genre in myEntities.Genres
    orderby genre.Name
    select new { genre.Name, genre.Reviews };
    GridView1.DataSource = allGenres;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Why is this `DataBind()`is used in the end. I have seen the MSDN document for`DataBind()`which says "(It) Binds a data source to the invoked server control and all its child controls."

And if I remove it, I get an error as "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

So I was just confused that what is this`DataBind()`actually does? I have seen some people using DataBind for DataGridView also, and I am not sure why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataBind method forces the datasource to be read and bound to the control. Since you databind within the `PlanetWroxEntities` context which you dispose afterwards, the control should read the data from the datasource before the `PlanetWroxEntities` disposes. In other words: before the database connection is closed.

A alternative is to force the query by calling the `.ToList()` method. This sets the `DataSource` property to a non-lazy list containing the concrete data.

```
using (PlanetWroxEntities myEntities = new PlanetWroxEntities())
{
    var allGenres = from genre in myEntities.Genres
    orderby genre.Name
    select new { genre.Name, genre.Reviews };
    GridView1.DataSource = allGenres.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why does this have only two likes? Best explanation I found on google after searching for 30 minutes.